# Embed image in excel as an object through apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to attach or embed a Image in my excel file with respect to each row. Is there any way to attach an image in excel that makes it embed inside the excel.

I am trying to do the following steps in excel,

Excel -> Insert -> Object -> Create from file -> here i select the file(image file) i want to add in excel

I want this to be done through apache poi.

Comment: There is a way to embed worksheet, document and slideshow but is there any source to embed image ?

Comment: How would you do this directly using `Excel`s GUI?

Comment: I want to do through java apache poi. Is there any way for that ? i have seen creating comments and including pictures in it, is there any way to do that using apache poi

Comment: `apache poi` is attempting to create the same kind of files like `Microsoft Offuce` does. So `apache poi` cannot do something what you are not able to do using `Microsoft Offuce`. So in terms of `Excel`: `apache poi` cannot do something what you cannot do using `Excel`s GUI. So please describe what you are doing using `Excel`s GUI (adding comments having pictures in them for example). Then we possibly will be able to sho how to do that using `apache poi`.

Comment: In excel I am adding an object. Excel -> Insert -> Object -> Create from file -> here i select the file(image file) i want to add in excel. Please tell me if you know how to do it in apache poi

Comment: OK, now the requirement is clear. But I have not a solution. Maybe others will have. But you should edit your question and providing that clear requirement **there**. Because others may not be willing to read all comments to get your requirement clear.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have edited my question